# Sharing code between two c# assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

1) I have a project called SocketServer in which there is a Class **Room**, this project is a complied exe and can also be complied as a DLL.

2) In Another project called, lets say, MyGame, there is a class called MyAwesomeGame, in which I need to do something like:

```
public class MyAwesomeGame
{
    public Init(Room room)
    {
        //I can get data from Room
    }
}
```

Now MyGame Project is compiled into a MyGame.DLL, and is placed somewhere relative to the SocketServer.exe, which at runtime loads MyGame.DLL and Instantiates MyAwesomeGame class and calls the Method Init and passes room as its parameter. Code is SocketServer project is something like:

```
public class Room
{
     private InstantiateGameRoom()
     {
          //Load External MyGame.DLL Assembly 
          Task<MyAwesomeGame> task = Task<MyAwesomeGame>.Factory.StartNew(() => (MyAwesomeGame)Activator.CreateInstance(classType, new object[] { this }));
          MyAwesomeGame instance = task.result;
          instance.init(this);
     }
}
```

So my question is how can I get reference of the Class **room** in MyGame Project? Should I add reference of my SocketServer Project? and if I do, wont it get complied into my MyGame.dll?

p.s: I also intend to distribute the socketserver.dll as an API to thrid-party users.

Comment: Yes, you add a reference of the project where the class is located. Just make sure both .dll:s are in the same directory and you should be fine

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but `Model`s and all stuff relative to them (according to me) should be placed in an indipendent project wich has no dependency and no knowledge about when and how they will be used and from who

Comment: Or option 3: move Room to a third project that is referenced by both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the SocketServer's generated dll to the references of the MyGame project. Right click on MyGame, click Add, click References..., in the dialog select Projects and select the SocketServer project.

I believe it is also wise to make sure that SocketServer is a depedency for the MyGame project to make sure SocketServer  is built before MyGame.

--edit: please read the comment below that I made after Sushant's clarification. Or go straight to Sid's answer. :-)

Comment: Just so that we are clear, SocketServer.DLL and SocketServer.exe are exactly the same, just the build output is different. So when I load MyGame.DLL in my SocketServer.exe, at runtime, won't there be any namespace issues? because I imagine MyGame.DLL already contains SocketServer Class references.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up as that changes things. I agree with @Sid's suggested solution. In general it is a good practice to prevent duplication. So put shared code in a dll that makes it available for multiple applications or other dll's. Also, why have a dll that has all the code that is already in the application?

Answer (score 2):

I think the proper way to share `Model`s among two or more projects is to extract all the models and relative logics to a **separate project**.

Then you can reference that project from every project that needs to use that data.

The scenario I am talking about is the following:

1. **ModelsProject** (Contains models and business logic)
2. **ProjectA** (has a dependency on ModelsProject)
3. **ProjectB** (has a dependency on ModelsProject)

### Scheme

[image]

Comment: Yes this is what I am planning to do, but just wanted to see if there is some other way.

Comment: @SushantPoojary well obviously you can put the models in `SocketServer ` but the down sides is that every project who will need to use the models will have to reference `SocketServer ` even if they don't need to use the logic relative to that project